Clio SSO - Keycloak / SupaBase
I'm trying to setup Clio (https://docs.developers.clio.com/guides/sso/sso-implementation-guide/) into Keycloak and then integrate into Supabase for authentication.
However, I am getting a bit confused with how to use Keycloak like this.
I tried to follow Supabase's documentation on Keycloak, however its super-outdated. I also tried to follow Keycloaks, but to no luck
